# How to get 2 columns of single and multiple occurrences of values from a column of ids in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has columns:

| customer | month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-22 |
| 2 | 2022-05-22 |
| 3 | 2022-05-22 |
| 1 | 2022-05-22 |
| 4 | 2022-05-22 |
| 3 | 2022-06-22 |
| 3 | 2022-06-22 |
| 1 | 2022-06-22 |
| 2 | 2022-06-22 |

and I want to get a result like:

| month | single_cust | multiple |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022-06-01 | 2 | 1 |

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you provide details on how the inputs relate to the outputs? @VRNNRV

Comment: @lemon I am sorry, i am a beginner to this, could you please elaborate on your question, so i can answer better?

Comment: How do you get rows `2022-05-01, 3, 1` and `2022-06-01, 2, 1` from the input table you provided? I'm trying to understand the logic hidden underneath. @VRNNRV

Comment: @lemon, that is the logic that I am trying to look for. The problem is something like: we have table 1 which shows the date on which customers from the customer column ordered something. I am trying to bifurcate the customers into the month that they ordered in and the two columns 'single' and 'multiple' get populated wrt the number of times they ordered in that particular month.